# Java synchronize items in two collections asynchronously using separate task

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, synchronization

I need some efficient code that could synchronize items in two Collections. I mean when one item is added to first collection it should be also added to second collection but adding item to second collection should be done asynchronously (eg. by separate task which will be called cyclically using Spring Boot scheduling task API) so that both Collections contains the same items.

There is assumption that there is only possibility to add new items

These synchronization should be effectively so that this algorithm can work in production environment.
Synchronization of both list should take up to few seconds

Could You please help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a volatile boolean field to signal and a synchronised queue to consuming elements (by the second thread)? The second thread will poll in a loop.

Comment: Are they lists? What about element removal?

Comment: So this second thread should be enclosed in infinite loop and fetch new items from first Collection ? What Collection implementation would be most efficient in this scenario ?

There is no removing functionality at all :)

Comment: @Thomas, if there's no removal, then (assuming both collections are lists), you can loop in second thread, and check collection size difference and then add `subList` into async the collection. I can't speak about efficiency: there's not enough data about how frequently the data changes and what kind of access to collection elements there must be.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to look in the direction of synchronization while reading from the second collection (ideally during recording in the first, but apparently this is impossible).

```
Object get(Object key) {
    if (compareCollectionsBySize()) //it should be a simple, inexpensive operation
    {
        return duplicateCollection.get(key);
    } else {
        //we need synchronization
        //it all depends on the duration of the synchronization
        //and search costs for the original collection

        //in case fast synchronization
        synchronizeCollections();
        return duplicateCollection.get(key);
    }
}
```